# Change value from an array

Tags: javascript

I have the next code:

```js
  const arr = [
    {
    name:'john',
    cars:[
      {audi:1},
      {bmw:2}
    ]
  },
  {
    name:'bill',
    cars:[
      {audi:10},
      {bmw:0}
    ]
  }
]
const arr1 = arr.map(i => {
  if(i.name === 'john') {
    return i.cars.map( a => {
      return {
        ...i,
        test:[2]
      }
    })
  }
  return i
})
console.log(arr1)
```

Here i want too loop through the array and for the first object to change the `cars` array, adding `test:[2]`. For this i used:

```js
const arr1 = arr.map(i => {
  if(i.name === 'john') {
    return i.cars.map( a => {
      return {
        ...i,
        test:[2]
      }
    })
  }
  return i
})
```

The issue is that my code don't return what i want. I get the first object like:

```js
0: Object
name: "john"
cars: Array[2]
test: 2
1: Object
name: "john"
cars: Array[2]
test: 2
```

but i need like this:

```js
 {
    name:'john',
    cars:[
      {
      audi:1,
      test: [2],
      },
      {bmw:2}
    ]
  },
```

How to solve my issue?

Comment: `i.cars[0].test = [2]` ?

Comment: @Cid That requires mutation, I bet he's using React or something that requires immutability

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to change the *first* item in the `cars` array, I don't think `map` is right - instead, just *list* the first changed car as an object literal inside an array, then spread the remaining cars into the array with `.slice(1)`:

```js
const arr = [
    {
    name:'john',
    cars:[
      {audi:1},
      {bmw:2}
    ]
  },
  {
    name:'bill',
    cars:[
      {audi:10},
      {bmw:0}
    ]
  }
]
const arr1 = arr.map(person => (
  person.name !== 'john'
  ? person
  : ({
      name: person.name,
      cars: [
        { ...person.cars[0], test: [2] },
        ...person.cars.slice(1)
      ]
    })
));
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could address the right position and add the wanted property.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'john', cars: [{ audi: 1 }, { bmw: 2 }] }, { name: 'bill', cars: [{ audi: 10 }, { bmw: 0 }] }],
    add = { target: [0, 0], value: { test: [2] } }
    result = data.map((o, i) => i === add.target[0]
        ? { ...o, cars: o.cars.map((p, j) => j === add.target[1]
            ? {... p, ...add.value }
            : p)
        }
        : o);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the desired result, a non mapping solution may be viable?

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'john',
    cars: [{
        audi: 1
      },
      {
        bmw: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'bill',
    cars: [{
        audi: 10
      },
      {
        bmw: 0
      }
    ]
  }
];

// clone the initial arr
const arrModified = Object.assign([], arr); 
// find John
const indexJohn = arrModified.findIndex(v => v.name === "john");
if (indexJohn > -1) {
  // modify the desired value
  arrModified[indexJohn].cars[0].test = [2];
}

console.log(arrModified[0].cars);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```